# Custom sleep mode for Windows PC

Tags: sleep, fan, noise

On my laptop I can close the lid, and the computer enters a mode where the fans stop running, allowing me to queue up downloads for the night without having to hear the fan noise.

Can something similar be achieved on my desktop pc without overheating any components?

Comment: The answer is probably "probably, unless you have a really inadequately cooled machine", but it would also be helpful to know what operating system.  If we're talking Windows, sleep is sleep, there's no difference between a laptop or desktop (beyond the fact that a laptop can be configured to sleep on detecting that you've closed the lid)

Comment: @Shinrai The term sleep might be confusing since the laptop does not actually sleep, it just turns it fans off, and some hardware not used I guess. Can I use something like a program to monitor the temperatures, and only if the temperatures are critical turn the monitors on?

btw, im using windows 7

Comment: I have no idea what your laptop would be doing where it would just selectively disable certain pieces of hardware that would include the system fans, unless it's possibly some manufacturer specific implementation.  Maybe somebody else knows, sorry. >.<